# AVAudioPlayer cannot play Audio (.wav) file written using ExtAudioFileWriteAsync

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avaudioplayer, extaudiofile

I used ExtAudioFileWriteAsync to write the recorded audio using RemoteIO into a .wav file. AVAudioPlayer is not playing the saved audio file. The audio file plays only on VLC media player but not in QuickTime or any other media players.

```
var player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioFileURL)
player.play()
```

Some basic details of audio file: [image]

Kindly suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wasting 2 days, I have found the issue is with not flushing the audio data using **ExtAudioFileDispose** call. As the final audio data was not flushed, the wav file was partial and corrupted. It was only played in VLC player and not any other players. After using the **ExtAudioFileDispose**, the Audio plays well with **AVAudioPlayer** also.

```
result = ExtAudioFileDispose(self.extAudioFileRef!)
```